# Access data inside dynamic components from parent component in VueJS + Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, store, vue-dynamic-components

I created this demo to explain better my goal: https://codepen.io/Albvadi/pen/OJMgByR

Each button create a new alert creating a object inside the vuex store in the components array. With the `component` property I know the type of the component to render.

Each alert generate a random string in a data property inside the component.
How do I need to configure the connection with Vuex to obtain the data from the child alert component inside the global components array?

Thanks!

Comment: Vuex already obtain the data of each alert component. Otherwise, how can **Json Data Component** show up the information?

Comment: Vuex has a array of components, but each component has a randomMessage property, data inside the component, that I need to obtain. I´d updated the example to show the random message in each alert

Comment: like [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rzjktv0h/), show the RandonMessage in each alert?

Comment: No, I need the inverse. In that fiddle, in each component you are fetching the `randomMessage` from the parent. In my real case, each component fetch `randomMessage` from Api and I need obtain that result in the parent. Obviously, `randomMessage ` it´s only an example. In my real project, it´s a object with tons of properties nested with input bindings editables.

Comment: like [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qb0Ltk6v/), click the primary alert then you will see the parent print something in the console.

Comment: uses the event is one solution the parent component get the data properties or others from child components. Another solution is using **provide/inject**, check [this questions and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52118421/pass-data-from-child-to-parent-without-events-just-on-load-it-s-possible-on-vue/52121295#52121295)

Comment: Yes @Sphinx, thanks!, it´s what I want, but I´m trying to avoid the use of emit, For this reason I am using Vue, to have all the information centralized in the same store and be the "source of truth"... Any more ideas?

Comment: I meant, "For this reason I am using VueX"

Comment: like [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3fea25v1/)? Both parent and child components can access Vuex.components

Comment: I´m not only need obtain the data, but must be in sync. If child change date, the parent must change data. Thanks for your help @Sphinx, I solved using a computed property...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved with a computed property that gives me the parent item. I don't know if it is the best way or if there is a simpler one, but I think it is the correct one.

```
computed: Vuex.mapState({
    getParentItem(state) {
        return state.components[state.components.indexOf(this.index)];
    }
}),
```

Demo solved: https://codepen.io/Albvadi/pen/wvMrpLv